# MPI: Why I have the error when I using MPI_Barrier in the next example?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm new in MPI and I want to do make a problem where I have 2 array A and B with 15 elements and I have 16 processes and and each process represent an element in the arrays (I don't use process zero). The array A have stored input data an positions 8...15, where this positions reprezent the leaves of a tree and in the first step I make a compression in array, where the leaves send the number to the parent and parent receives from all sons and add the numbers and send to father. And the array A si done at process 1 where is the sum of all elements in the array. And in the second step I make prefix calculations where I start from process 0 and finish at leaves. 
And to calculate the array B all the other processes need to wait the process 1 to finish the work and for that I using a MPI_Barrier but I have a error when I exec the code.

```
int m = 3;
int n = (int)pow(2, m);
int *A = (int*)malloc(2 * n * sizeof(int));
int *B = (int*)malloc(2 * n * sizeof(int));
int id;
MPI_Status status;
A[8] = 4; A[9] = 8; A[10] = 5; A[11] = 2;
A[12] = 10; A[13] = 6; A[14] = 9; A[15] = 11;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);   
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
if (id == 1)
{
    int nr;
    int suma = 0;
    MPI_Recv(&nr, 1, MPI_INT, 2 * id, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    suma += nr;
    MPI_Recv(&nr, 1, MPI_INT, 2 * id + 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    suma += nr;
    A[id] = suma;
    printf("A[%d]=%d\n", id, A[id]);
    B[id] = A[id];
    printf("B[%d]=%d\n", id, B[id]);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else
{
    if (id != 0)
    {
        if(id >= 8)
        {
            MPI_Send(&A[id], 1, MPI_INT, id / 2, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("%d a trimis %d catre %d\n", id, A[id], id / 2);
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else
        {
            int nr;
            int suma = 0;
            MPI_Recv(&nr, 1, MPI_INT, 2 * id, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            suma += nr;
            MPI_Recv(&nr, 1, MPI_INT, 2 * id + 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            suma += nr;
            A[id] = suma;
            MPI_Send(&A[id], 1, MPI_INT, id / 2, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("%d a trimis %d catre %d\n", id, A[id], id / 2);
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        if (id % 2 == 1)
        {
            B[id] = B[(id - 1) / 2];
            printf("B[%d]=%d\n", id, B[id]);
        }
        else
        {
            B[id] = B[id / 2] - A[id + 1];
            printf("B[%d]=%d\n", id, B[id]);
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    free(A);
    return 0;
```

And I receive the next error:

> [15]fatal error 
>  Fatal error in MPI_Barrier:Other MPI error,
>   error stack:
>  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
>  failed to
>   attach to a bootstrap queue - 5064:344

How can I do to make the program work?

Comment: Does a more basic Init/Barrier/Finalize work on your system?

Answer (score 2):

`MPI_Barrier()` is a collective operation, and it will completes once invoked by **all** the MPI tasks from the communicator.

If i read correctly your code, task `0` does not invoke `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)`, so your program will deadlock unless some mechanism in the MPI library aborts it.